# Output audio from localstorage javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, local-storage

I'm doing a user generated sound composition. On the first page I provided 3 different sound sample and user have to pick 1 out of 3 using the multiple choice box and hit the next button. The output page will then play the sound sample that the user selected. 
My Code is as follow:

**1st Page:**

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <div><STRONG>Question 1</STRONG>: Please choose a sound.
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="saveharmony"onclick="savedharmony('sound1')">
  <audio id="sound" src="harmony1.mp3" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="saveharmony" onclick="savedharmony('sound1')">
  <audio id="sound" src="harmony2.mp3" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
    <a href="sound2.html" onclick="savedharmony('sound1')" style="clear:both;
  </body>
  </html>

  <script>
    var savedharmony = function (sound){
    localStorage.setItem("sound1","sound")};
    savedharmony('sound1');
  </script>
```

**Output Page:**

```
  <script>
    var sound1 = document.getElementById('sound1');
    new Audio();
    sound1.play();
  </script>
```

Here is some more context on what it is: http://nugenthomas.github.io/Demo/1st.html

Help would be really appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: `setItem()` requires 2 argments... a key name and a value string

Comment: @charlietfl Thank You, I totally missed that.

Comment: 1. duplicate IDs on `<audio>` 2.(*implied from 1*) using `savedharmony('sound1')` on both `<input>`s  3.Notice something wrong here ? `setItem("sound1","sound")` *Hint: see function parameter*